# Setup integration test method that returns a string array

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, integration-testing, moq

I have method that reads and returns data from the database, now this method checks if the returned model is not null then if not it goes and gets the fields that I wanted to return and returns them in an array if strings, here is the method

```
public string[] GetCustomerSecret(string publicKey)
{
    var customer = _directConnectContext.Customers.Single(c => c.PublicKey == publicKey);
    if (null != customer)
    {
        return new[] { customer.PrivateKey, customer.HttpReferer ?? string.Empty};
    }        
    return null;
}
```

So I want to setup in integration or unit test(not sure which one it is really) method to test, I am using Mock and my tests have been working fine so far but I am struggling with this specific one, here is what I have tried, the below codes mocks the list of customers

```
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer { 
        CustomerID = 1,
        PublicKey = "11111",
        PrivateKey = "121112A",
        PartnerName = "TestParter",
        PartnerIata = "56858VB",
        PartnerID = "67607", 
        PartnerActive = true,
        HttpReferer="RefererTest"
    }
};
```

Then here is the actual setup which I need assistance with

```
customerMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetCustomerSecret(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string publicKey) => customerList.Where(x => x.PublicKey == publicKey)).ToArray());
```

It gives an error that reads,

> "cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a
>   delegate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to replicate what is being done in the actual implmentation, then perform similar actions with the mock setup.

```
customerMock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetCustomerSecret(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string publicKey) => {
        var customer = customerList.Single(x => x.PublicKey == publicKey);
        return new[] { customer.PrivateKey, customer.HttpReferer ?? string.Empty};
    });
```